# Link dropdown values with Buttons to select values of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to design a dropdown such that it takes value range as 10, 20,30,50,70,100,150,200,300,700,1000,2000, and 5000. I also want two buttons for which I  can assign value_up or value_down. which will get value range as mentioned above. Drop down will allow user to select values from above set manually where as value_up or value_down would allow to increase or decrease value for the above range. Could you please help me to achieve this using javascript? I have a basic functionality written here bu it is not doing the function as explained above.

Javascript:

var sensitivityFlag=0;

```
//// Sensitivity up ////
        function value_Up(){
            sensitivityFlag = 1;
        }

        //// Sensitivity down ////
        function value_Down(){
            sensitivityFlag = -1;
        }

        function sensitivity(x){
            sens = 1*x/1000;

            switch (sensitivityFlag){
        case -1:
            sensitivity_Down();
            break
        case 1:
            sensitivity_Up();
            break
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the "Sensitivity" value, you may refer my [sample code here](https://jsfiddle.net/drmd21yt/)

```
function value_Up()
{
  var sensitivity=document.getElementById("sensitivitySelect");
  if (sensitivity.selectedIndex<(sensitivitySelect.options.length-1))
    sensitivity.selectedIndex++;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I will try for value_down(). Hope its length +1.

Comment: If my solution works, please set my solution as answer.

Comment: Yes it is perfectly changing the values as per my requirement. But the issue is it is not reflecting the functionality per say. along the value change it has to change the functionality as well. as it is done by sensitivity function.

Comment: You need to add  sensitivity.onchange(); statement after the sensitivity.selectedIndex++;